# What to use between a sticky floor and interlocking vinyl tiles (a floating floor)

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I didn't want to install luxury interlocking tiles over the existing floor because there were already two layers of vinyl tiles on the floor and it would be too high.

After removing the old tiles, the residual glue is causing the wood floor to be sticky.

I'll probably put red rosin paper down on the sticky floor and install the floating interlocking tiles over that.

Is this OK or am I missing something?  Is there a better solution?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rosin paper or felt would work fine. I have used felt paper in the past because I had it in the shop.

Comment: Are you referring to ordinary felt that is rated by "lb" and is used for roofing? As floor underlayment you don't overlap it, right?

Comment: It is lighter than roofing I think 30# where I use 90# for roofing if I remember correctly we used to use it for siding before tyvek and other house wraps became avaiable. Less tar but is solid and in my area I haven't seen rosin paper for a while but I am sure it is still available. It also came in wider rolls.

Comment: Thanks.  Is felt the same as tar paper?   I wouldn't want the tiles to stick or bind to it.